# How to create/copy a file into hugetlbfs

Tags: linux

I'm trying to copy shared libraries on **hugetlbfs** mounts but for some reason it fails. I could create directories and files but actually could not write in. So all files get zero size and "invalid argument" error is being reported.

Here is short bash listing showing a problem. Same things happen as root.

```
[aivanov@aiws pagesize-2MB]$ mount | grep huge
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
none on /var/lib/hugetlbfs/user/aivanov/pagesize-2MB type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,pagesize=2097152)
none on /var/lib/hugetlbfs/user/aivanov/pagesize-1GB type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,pagesize=1073741824) 
none on /mnt type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,seclabel)
[aivanov@aiws pagesize-2MB]$ pwd
/var/lib/hugetlbfs/user/aivanov/pagesize-2MB
[aivanov@aiws pagesize-2MB]$ ls -la
total 0
drwxrwxrwx. 2 root    root  0 Oct 27 16:59 .
drwx------. 4 aivanov root 44 Oct 17 17:13 ..
[aivanov@aiws pagesize-2MB]$ mkdir Dir1
[aivanov@aiws pagesize-2MB]$ cd Dir1/
[aivanov@aiws Dir1]$ echo ABC >> test
bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
[aivanov@aiws Dir1]$ ll
total 0
-rw-rw-r--. 1 aivanov aivanov 0 Oct 27 17:00 test
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hugetlbfs is not a normal filesystem where you can store files in. It is a simply a mechanism to allocate huge pages for programs that can utilize the benefits of huge pages.

Therefore you cannot write files there.

Comment: Thanks for reply, basically this question is related to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40285971/how-to-load-text-segments-of-shared-libraries-into-huge-pages-on-linux] 
So I'm trying to load shared library backed by huge pages. According to what I see in /proc/PID/smaps there is some way libhugetlbfs is creating files there that are then used to represent .text segments of executable. Is it possible to reuse this outsede of libhugetlbfs?

Comment: I don't know this for sure, since I've not been in that close contact with programming Linux software with linked libraries lately. However, my educated guess is that the application / library needs always to initiate the usage of huge pages. On another point, huge page size is 4MB by default, and it is rare that a library is this large. So, you would be wasting memory by allocating a huge page for a library that doesn't use the huge page completely.